# Get MAC of a client request?

Tags: php, authentication, openvpn, mac-address

I have a network with 20 raspberries (clients) and 1 server.
I'd like to check MAC of client request, is that possible ?

Further, possible without being known (nor visible) by the client ?

NB : I aim to check if a client is not a fake one/imitation.
NB2 : I already run a VPN option. But I want to check MAC anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your server a Linux host?

If you have a white list of your clients, you can use `iptables` to accept requests only from them on specific input ports.  You can also log requests from bad clients in dmesg.

The following script defines `MACCHECK` chain to accept packets from approved 3 MACs, and drop others with logging.  Then routes all packets of tcp/80 or tcp/443 in `INPUT` chain to `MACCHECK`.

```
iptables -N MACCHECK
iptables -A MACCHECK -m mac --mac-source xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -j ACCEPT
iptables -A MACCHECK -m mac --mac-source yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy -j ACCEPT
iptables -A MACCHECK -m mac --mac-source zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:zz -j ACCEPT
iptables -A MACCHECK -m limit --limit 3/hour -j LOG --log-prefix "Bad host: "
iptables -A MACCHECK -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j MACCHECK   # Checking all HTTP requests
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j MACCHECK  # Checking all HTTPS requests
```

Note that all your clients should be in the same network as your server's.

Comment: Thanks. My server is a Linux (CentOS 6.6). // Yaegashi : a great solution thks, my noobness bout ipTables ...

Comment: @ArchiT3K Updated to make it more useful and easy to maintain.  I recommend to use `iptables-save` / `iptables-restore` once you can make a working setting.

Answer (score 2):

If there's a *direct* connection between your Raspberry Pi and the client, i.e. there's no routing **and** both are in the same [segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_segment), it's possible. Just use an ARP resolution, e.g. : `arp <client_ip_address>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the MAC of the client only if the client is on the same network segment, i.e. if there's no router in between (a switch is ok). You can see that with traceroute: if you run `traceroute 192.0.2.1` from the server where 192.0.2.1 is the address of one of the devices, it must report only a single hop, the destination. [Nasha's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206804) and [yaegashi's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206805) answers explain how you can do this.

However, even if you can, checking the MAC doesn't really provide any security, because the MAC can be easily faked. Most Ethernet devices can have their MAC set in software.

To identify a hardware device, there's basically a single way: cryptography. Store a [private key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) on the device, and have it perform an authentication operation that proves that it possesses the private key.

Since you're apparently using a web application, there's a tool for this: a [TLS client certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake). Use the HTTPS protocol and have the client use its private key to authenticate to the web server.

Though depending on how you're using this VPN, it may (or may not) provide a similar capability.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I ve already put encryption (OpenVPN network). I wanted to add checkers, as MAC auth., in case of a rasp key is stolen... It seems so simple to do this (steal a rasp, browse disk, copy vpn client config and key...) > thread @ http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207023/openvpn-protect-your-clients-key-cert-conf-from-being-stolen

Comment: @ArchiT3K If the key is stolen, it's just as easy to copy the MAC. Checking the MAC brings you no extra security.

Comment: I was betting on one fact : the hacker does not know he needs the MAC... naive, I guess. Well, thank you, I m going to read about VPN security, it seems just the first step to do. Would you know a particularly good book about it ?

Comment: @ArchiT3K [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) very rarely works. In your case, it would be trivial to guess: the hacker would look at traffic from a legitimate device and from the non-working copy, see what differs, and change the MAC on the copy.